# Aspect(-like) function for closures

Tags: grails, groovy, aop, taglib

In Grails (at least up to the current version 2.2), taglibs are closures. For certain taglib closures, I'd like to use some "around" type advice / wrap the closure in an interceptor.

To put it another way, let's say there is this taglib straight from the Grails doc:

```
class SimpleTagLib {
   def emoticon = { attrs, body ->
      out << body() << (attrs.happy == 'true' ? " :-)" : " :-(")
   }
}
```

Now, without modifying the taglib code, I'd like to time how long "emoticon" takes to execute.

Spring AOP (and all other AOP I can find) only seems to work on Java methods - and taglibs are always based on closures. An "around" pointcut would be perfect for this, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: What about an around pointcut in either the `getProperty` or `missingProperty`? Not sure how grails obtains the closure property

Comment: Maybe a simpler approach is to change the behavior of your closure with metaClass.

Comment: Please add a JIRA feature request to the Grails Jira. This is a feature missing from Grails. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6680?focusedCommentId=56175&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-56175 for one more use case (taglib caching).

Answer (score 1):

I've written something similar which I put as a public closure in a category I then mixin to services:

```
// TimingCategory.groovy
/**
 * Provides common AOP timing functionality to Services which mixin this category.
 */
class TimingCategory {

    static Closure timer = { String label = "The call", Closure closure ->
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        def result = closure.call()
        Long end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        Long duration = end - start
        log.warn "${label} took ${duration} ms"
        return result
    }
}
```

In other classes, you just reference the `timer` closure as such:

```
@Mixin(TimingCategory)
public class WhateverService {

    public String doSomeWork() {
        timer "Doing a lot of work", {
            1000.times { doSomething() }
            someMethodWithAStringReturnValue()
        }
    }
 }
```

That will give you log output of **"WARN: Doing a lot of work took nn ms"** and return the value of the inner closure as the return value of the `doSomeWork` method.

For your taglib instance, just wrap the `out << ...` in the

```
timer "Writing an emoticon", { 
    // your code
}
```

code.

If you don't care about passing through the internal return value, you could instead return the duration as the result of the closure invocation.

**Update**:

I might have misread -- you're asking how to wrap the taglib execution without modifying the taglib code at all? What about creating a custom taglib which accepts the body and passes it to the other taglibs for execution?

I haven't tried this, but something like:

```
class TimedTagLib {

    static namespace = "timer"

    def timedTag = { attrs, body ->
        timer "Executing the timed tag", {
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

And invoking it like

```
<timer:timedTag><g:emoticon whatever="something">Text</g:emoticon></timer:timedTag>
```

**Update 2:**

Ok, so I tried it. Works fine. My final code (I added a second timer closure which returns the duration):

```
// TimedTagLib.groovy
@Mixin(TimingCategory)
class TimedTagLib {
    static namespace = "timer"

    def timedTag = { attrs, body ->
        def duration = returnTimer "Printing the timed tag", {
            out << body()
        }

        out << "Took ${duration} ms to print"
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
// someView.gsp
<timer:timedTag>
    <g:formatLocalDate date="${LocalDate.now()}" />
</timer:timedTag>
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
03/19/2013
Took 6 ms to print
```

And it also wrote to the log.